# Distinguish between 9" and 10" tablet layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, portrait

I am trying to find the right qualifiers to distinguish a layout between a 10" tablet(Nexus10) and the 9" tablet(Nexus9). This is for portrait layouts, what I have landscape works fine for both screens.

So far I have been unable to find the right combination.

Also I have been unable to make the hdp-port layout folder qualifier work either. It seems to always to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I have it and it works fine:

The directory `-sw720dp` is for 9" tablet resources and `-sw800dp` is for 10" tablet resources.

Comment: I couldn't get the height restrictions to work but just adding a sw720dp and sw800dp was enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The qualification h< N >dp should do the trick here. According to the  [Resources Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), this qualification:

> Specifies a minimum available screen height, in "dp" units at which the resource should be used—defined by the < N > value. This configuration value will change when the orientation changes between **landscape** and **portrait** to match the current actual height.

As your tablet is in portrait, the height of a 10'' will have a higher minimum available height than the 9'' and that could make the distinction for your different layouts. So the qualification for 10'' portrait should be layout-h1600dp.